# Webpack output does not honor its own renamed concatenated modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-stream

I have a simple node project where I use webpack-stream (via Gulp) to bundle multiple JS files into one output file. The webpack must concatenate the files in such a way that it looks as if you wrote all the code in one file.

For example, the runtime of the output file expects a `startTest()` function to be declared globally.

For this reason I have disabled certain optimizations that would encapsulate or otherwise minify the output code.

Consider the following simplified code of my project:

**main.js:**

```
import VoiceGender from "./models/VoiceGender";

console.log(VoiceGender.MALE);

function startTest() {
  console.log(VoiceGender.MALE);
}
```

**VoiceGender.js:**

```
const VoiceGender = {
  MALE: 'M',
  FEMALE: 'F'
}

export default VoiceGender;
```

**The webpack configuration:**

```
{
   "mode":"production",
   "output":{
      "iife":false,
      "filename":"bundle.js"
   },
   "optimization":{
      "minimize":false,
      "usedExports":false,
      "mangleExports":false
   },
   "cache":{
      "type":"filesystem"
   }
}
```

**bundle.js (webpack output):**

```
/******/ "use strict";
/******/ // The require scope
/******/ var __webpack_require__ = {};
/******/ 
/************************************************************************/
/******/ /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/ (() => {
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/ })();
/******/ 
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
// ESM COMPAT FLAG
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);

;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./src/models/VoiceGender.js
const VoiceGender_VoiceGender = {
    MALE: "M",
    FEMALE: "F"
};

/* harmony default export */ const models_VoiceGender = (VoiceGender_VoiceGender);
;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./src/main.js


console.log(models_VoiceGender.MALE);

function startTest() {
    console.log(VoiceGender.MALE);
}
```

Notice that the `console.log(..)` above the `startTest()` function uses the generated name by Webpack (which is fine), but inside the `startTest()` function it does not use that reference. This is the wrong reference because Webpack declared the module under `models_VoiceGender` and `VoiceGender_VoiceGender` instead of `VoiceGender`.

I have no idea what could be causing this. Maybe a bug? I tried playing around with certain properties but I don't see any change.

**webpack-stream version:** ^7.0.0

**gulp version:** ^4.0.2

**webpack version (via webpack-stream):** ^5.21.2

---

**UPDATE:**
When adding `export` to the `startTest()` function, the reference is fixed. Alternatively, calling `startTest()` inside that script would also fix the reference. I have configured webpack to not exclude "unused" code, but it seems it does not properly bundle the unused code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've let this sit for a little bit to see if more people could weigh in on this, but I'm thinking that this is really more of a bug or a side effect of webpack and I should report it there.

Basically, webpack is configured to keep unused code. Even though the runtime will call the `startTest()` function, webpack doesn't know that so for webpack this is unused code.

For some reason, webpack doesn't do the "effort" to use the correct module names in "unused" code. I assume this is a bug.

A workaround is to make the code appear used by:

1. Adding `export` to the function
2. Calling the function in the JS (not suitable for my use case)

So in the end, the workarounds are fine and perhaps they are semantically correct.